# Prove that for all integers, if $a$ is even and $b$ is odd then $a^{2}+3b$ is odd.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Theorem: For all integers, if $a$ is even and $b$ is odd then $a^{2}+3b$ is odd.

So far my proof is as follows:
 Let $a$ be any even integer
 Let $b$ be any odd integer

By the definition of even integers, $\exists k\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a = 2k$ and by the definition of odd integers, $\exists  j\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $b = 2j+1$.

Therefore, 
$$\begin{align}
 a^2 - 3b &= (2k)^2 - 3(2j+1) \\
&=4k^2-6j-3 \\
&=(4k^2-6j-4)+1 \\
&=2(2k^2-3j-2)+1 \\
&= 2m + 1 \quad \text{where } m=2k^2-3j-2 \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align}$$

So, by definition of odd integers, $a^2-3b=2m+1$ is odd.

Is this correct, and if so is there anywhere I can improve it? I just started doing Discrete Math at my university, so any help would be great.

Comment: No issues, that looks like a good proof for the tools you have used. I have edited your post to use {align} just for appearance.

Comment: Are you familiar with congruence's in number theory?

Comment: @rrogers I don't believe so, no.

Comment: @amhokies One question: at the beginning you have a² + 3b, but at the end you have a² - 3b. Really, it is not so important for the proof, but it is for the website and probably for your professor. Can you check?

Comment: If you would like I can write down a three (5?) proof; but I think you should look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation  -----------It's basically operating on remainders after division; boy am I going to get hate mail over that characterization:)  Then look at the definition at this:---When an algebraic structure includes more than one operation, congruence relations are required to be compatible with each operation. For example, a ring possesses both addition and multiplication, and a congruence relation on a ring must satisfy
r1 + s1 ≡ r2 + s2    and    r1s1 ≡ r2s2